# cannot compile FutureTask inner class creation

Tags: java, generics, concurrency

The below code will not compile (JDK 1.8.0_40) and I am not able to understand why.

```
public abstract class BackgroundThread<T> {
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private final FutureTask<T> task;

    public <T> BackgroundThread() {
        this.task = new FutureTask<T>(new Callable<T>() {
            @Override
            public T call() throws Exception {
                return BackgroundThread.this.perform();
            }
        });
    }

    public abstract T perform() throws Exception;

    public abstract void onDone();

    public abstract void setProgress(int i);

    public final void start() {

    }
}
```

**Error message: 
Error(17, 53) Java incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T**

Comment: solved! it was the type parameter from the constructor that needs to be removed. Intellij also helped: "Type parameter T hides type parameter T"

Answer (score 2):

Remove the type parameter from the constructor as it defines a type variable whose scope is totally different than the variable with the same name `T` in the class declaration:

```
public BackgroundThread() {
```